# site to site VPN between GPC and Fortinet 800C

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, vpn

I have a VPN site to site configuration Fortinet800C and Google Cloud VPN as link: https://cloud.google.com/files/CloudVPNGuide-UsingCloudVPNwithFortinetFortiGate300C.pdf.

But it's not successful.The logs look like this repeated over and over:

```
16:43:36.240
sending packet: from 146.148.29.x[500] to 27.72.57.x[500] (640 bytes)
16:43:36.547
received packet: from 27.72.57.x[500] to 146.148.29.x[500] (360 bytes)
16:43:36.548
parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No ]
16:43:36.548
27.72.57.x is initiating an IKE_SA
16:43:36.559
generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(MULT_AUTH) ]
16:43:36.559
sending packet: from 146.148.29.x[500] to 27.72.57.x[500] (384 bytes)
16:43:36.565
received packet: from 27.72.57.x[500] to 146.148.29.x[500] (360 bytes)
16:43:36.565
parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No ]
16:43:36.571
authentication of '146.148.29.x' (myself) with pre-shared key
16:43:36.571
establishing CHILD_SA vpn_27.72.57.x{1}
16:43:36.571
generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) IDr AUTH SA TSi TSr N(EAP_ONLY) ]
16:43:36.572
sending packet: from 146.148.29.x[500] to 27.72.57.x[500] (316 bytes)
16:43:36.885
received packet: from 27.72.57.x[500] to 146.148.29.x[500] (204 bytes)
16:43:36.886
parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi AUTH N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) SA TSi TSr ]
16:43:36.886
looking for peer configs matching 146.148.29.x[%any]...27.72.57.x[192.168.0.x]
16:43:36.886
no matching peer config found
16:43:36.886
generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
16:43:36.886
sending packet: from 146.148.29.x[500] to 27.72.57.x[500] (76 bytes)
16:43:36.891
received packet: from 27.72.57.x[500] to 146.148.29.x[500] (124 bytes)
16:43:36.891
parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr AUTH N(TS_UNACCEPT) ]
16:43:36.891
authentication of '192.168.0.x' with pre-shared key successful
16:43:36.891
constraint check failed: identity '27.72.57.x' required
16:43:36.891
selected peer config 'vpn_27.72.57.x' inacceptable: constraint checking failed
16:43:36.891
no alternative config found
16:43:36.891
generating INFORMATIONAL request 2 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
16:43:36.891
sending packet: from 146.148.29.x[500] to 27.72.57.x[500] (76 bytes)
16:43:37.887
received packet: from 27.72.57.x[500] to 146.148.29.x[500] (360 bytes)
16:43:37.888
parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No ]
16:43:37.888
27.72.57.140 is initiating an IKE_SA
16:43:37.900
generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(MULT_AUTH) ]
```

I'd be very grateful if someone can spot my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that cloud VPN and Fortinet device are not configured to the same IKE version. Please check that.

Also, try looking at the status message of the VPN as displayed in the cloud console, or using 'gcloud compute vpn-tunnels describe' in command line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one or more of the phase 1 setting did not match up on both sides. Without looking at the actual config, I cannot determine. But generally, check the pre-shared key, authentication and encryption algorithm, DH groups, IP of the remote gateway and the outgoing interface of the connection. These factors have to match. Also, if you have NAT-Traversal enabled on one end, it has to be enabled on the other end as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answers. The logs says, that phase 1 could not be established. So the parameters are not equal.

It seems, that the psk (pre-shared key) is equal:
"authentication of '192.168.0.x' with pre-shared key successful"

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30272680)